# WcfWebApi in Windows Azure WebRole always returns 404, but is fine locally

Tags: c#, azure, wcf-web-api

I'm stuck on the dreaded "it works locally" issue.

I have used NuGet to install the WcfWebApi into an Azure WebRole.
This is a WebForms website.

Global.asax.cs Application_Start calls RegisterRoutes().

RegisterRoutes() contains:`RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MySvc/TheService/", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Services.TheService)));`

The Service's Interface contains:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/hello", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string Hello();
```

The implementing class just returns "hello", so if I now navigate to: http://localhost:49831/MySvc/TheService/hello - i get "hello" returned. OK.

If I now publish to Azure and try the same url (obviously with xx.cloudapp.net/ etc) I always get a 404.

I have used the WcfWebApi before in the past - but always in a WCfWebRole. Does this make a difference? Why does it work locally? It must be something to do with Azure then?

Any advise appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:** well, as per @Rajesh's suggestion I ran Get_HostedServices, which listed the hosted-services urls, eg: https://management.core.windows.net/mysubscriptionId/services/hostedservices/the-nameOfTheApp. Not really sure where this is going...

In utter desperation I added a .svc file to a folder in my web app, plus all the (horrible) system.serviceModel services and so on that one needs for REST style configuration. This all works.

I don't want to close this question though as it's not been answered as such and I am curious as to what  has happened. Thanks everyone for responses so far. If I do find an answer I'll update.

Comment: Some information on how to list all the hosted services is give provided at this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460781.aspx

Comment: @Rajesh: thanks, but i'm pretty sure that just lists the hosted Azure services. I know the WebRole is up - I can see it. Just not WcfWebApi route endpoint that is *within* the WebRole hosted Service. thx anyway

Comment: Does it not show the location of the service when your try to see the list of hosted services as said above. Also try to browse to the service in IE on the Azure server from IIS and its should give you the path and from there you should be able to figure out the location of the resource.

Comment: It's strange, I am doing approximatly the same thing on http://www.clubcaprice.com/map and it works quite well. Are you sure you don't have anything on your web.config which could provoke an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about your issue, Could you try to run your app locally using IIS or IIS Express? (IIS express isn't available out of the box, you must install it, but is easier to use with VS)

The url you provided lead me to think that VS uses either Cassini (Visual Studio Development Server) or IIS express. Be aware that Cassini doesn't work exactly as IIS, whereas IIS Express does. Your Azure web role will run under IIS, which could explain the different behaviors you are experiencing.

Furthermore your url doesn't look like a Windows Azure emulator url (the domain should be something like 127.0.0.1:**81** .

I suppose your project is a windows azure project. When testing, are you sure you are starting the Azure project and NOT the web application project?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input. The original service (created via WebServiceHostFactory()) works in the emulator; in the VS Development Server; in IIS Express (with the webrole set as startup project) and in full IIS 7 on win2008 server. The only place it doesn't work is in an Azure WebRole

Comment: Could you put online a zip containing a sample demonstrating your issue, as I really don't understand the difference and would like to do some testing myself?

Comment: Good idea. I will try to construct a sample and post it. This might take a few days but I will try. Thanks.